# O365 SharePoint Recycle Bin to have additional columns like Title

Tags: sharepoint-online, recycle-bin

O365 Recycle bin has items that are deleted from the site with Deleted By User and Deleted time. Let us know if there is a way to include Title column for the deleted item.

Answer (score 0):

The view for the RecycleBin (`/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx`) is not customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Nils said, it is an application page which cannot be customized. As there is no way to edit the view for your requirements, it simply cannot be done. You can post in [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) if you really want this feature.